# Ionic2: Saving file to localstorage

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I could able to send my file to external web server using input type= file. Now, I want to save a word document/rtf/pdf file to local storage. And, if I click on one button, the local storage file must be sent to external web service using post request. Please suggest me on how to do this?

Comment: Have to store that file in device storage and you can store file in local storage only

Comment: There is a way to save on the device storage, like this:
`moveFile(path, fileName, newPath, newFileName)` or `copyFile(...)`, please check more information [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/#moveFile).

Comment: Device storage is also fine. Move file might not work as I'm saving by selecting file using input type=file. How do we get the filePath? And, once we save to device, how to send that as multi part request? Thanks in advance